# Step down ac transformer

Tags: transformer

I bought this small cheap transformer for my nest hello smart bell, it has 3 input options "4 wires" if i use 220v input wires it gives me 30 volt output without load of course.
If i use the 440 input wires it gives me 15 volt output, also without load.
My question is:
Is it safe to use the 440 input wires with my 230v outlet socket?

[image][image]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PkvA.jpg):

Comment: why? ..........

Answer (score 3):

You could power it between the 440V and 110V wires and get 18VAC under full load and probably about 20VAC open, which is well within the 16-24VAC operating range of the bell. The VA is adequate.

It's *claimed* to be a Class 2 transformer (though notably bereft of any visible markings and file numbers indicating that it has been tested to meet that requirement) so it **should** (they say) fail safely, **however having such things in a grounded metal enclosure or otherwise mounted to something non-flammable is never a bad idea IMHO.**

Comment: 20v between the 110 and 440, yesssss, you are right, you are the man :)

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it safe to use the 440 input wires with my 230v outlet socket?*

It won't damage the transformer and should provide you with about half the VA rated output stated on the label. Given that it is a 40 VA transformer you can expect to use this for a 20 VA load.

However, your load requires a 16 volt AC output and, running at 440 volt AC, the transformer only produces 15 volt AC so there is a shortfall. It may work or it may not but, it should be safe.

If you test it and it all looks fine, keep an eye on it for a couple of hours just to be sure.